# How do I keep <span thmr="foo"> tags from displaying?

Tags: theming

I have a field in a view that shows some HTML tags that, no matter what I do, keep showing up:

[image: Screenshot of a page with errant tags]

What's adding them? How do I get rid of them?

Comment: no, I create a **view** and set the **format** to **quicktabs**, then I set that quicktabs uses **title field** as tab name. I'll upload an screenshot to show these settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the [Theme Developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module installed, which adds `<span thmr="foo">` tags to everything.

> Firebug for Drupal themeing. See the screenshot and screencast. Note that this module injects markers into the DOM to do its magic. This may cause some themes to behave erratically and less capable browsers may make it worse (especially IE). Enable it when needed, and disable it afterwards.

The module uses a bit of brute forcing when it comes to adding those tags, and this can cause problems with complex themes that don't go out of their way to support it.

Disable it and they'll go away. You should only have that module enabled during development/debugging, anyway.